# What would the loss be in an aluminium generator with a gauge increase to compensate for the lower resistivity?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrical-resistance

Copper seems to be the clear winner against aluminium for the coils of a generator, however, all the resources I can find simply talk about the difference in resistivity.
If you use a thicker wire you can surely end up with a lower resistance for the aluminium wire than the thinner copper one.

Given that is the case; where does the disadvantage come in an aluminium generator with a higher gage of wire such that its resistance through the generator is lower than its equivalent copper generator?

My intuition is that it has something to do with being able to more tightly loop around the core and therefore intersect a stronger magnetic flux? Is this the case?

Comment: Aluminum doesn't work well in electrical wiring.  In the past, houses were wired with aluminum because it was less expensive than copper.  Over time, corrosion in screw connections at electrical outlets led to a lot of electrical resistance and heat, leading to house fires.

Comment: Sure but if used in a sealed unit the corrosion won't be an issue. As far as I am aware it isn't an issue for mains cables which use aluminium.

Comment: I've never seen an absolutely sealed electrical generator because there must be a motor (or turbine) shaft driving it, and that shaft has to come from outside the generator.  It could have a nitrogen purge on the casing, but this would be a continuous expense that would add up over time and probably be more expensive than copper over the lifetime of the generator.  Many things are possible, but in the real world, economics matter.

Comment: If you make the windings larger, the magnets need to move to make room so the flux density goes down.

Comment: @Hilmar do you know what the difference in efficiency would be for the decrease in flux density?

Comment: @DavidWhite - aluminum works just fine in electrical wiring, being preferred for larger gauges. Look at the feeder wires in your panel some time, and ask a good electrician about their torque spec. The issue is the smaller wire gauges used inside the house, backstab connections, and general ignoring of torque specs.